# Is is possible to use Dreamweaver to create Typescript?

Tags: dreamweaver, typescript

Is is possible to use Dreamweaver to create Typescript? either as an editor or in some fashion to compile?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you will be able to get the full TypeScript experience in Dreamweaver. The beauty of tools like Visual Studio or Web Storm is that you can design-time support, compilation-time checking and compilation to JavaScript all built in.

I can't find any documentation for the two major things you would need to bring TypeScript support to Dreamweaver:

1. Language support extensibility (a language definition of some kind)
2. Running an external application on save (to run the compiler)

You could probably get enough just with language support by running the compiler manually (probably by adding the command to a batch file) - but I cannot find any information on how to add a language to Dreamweaver.